# Windows Activation in Parallels and Boot Camp

Tags: windows, mac, parallels, boot-camp

When I got my new iMac a few months ago, I set up Boot Camp to split the disk into two. I bought and installed a copy of Windows 7 using Boot Camp. Everything worked great.

I recently bought and installed Parallels 6 and set up a VM to use my existing Boot Camp partition.

When I boot into Windows 7 from Parallels, Windows gripes about activation and has given me 3 days to activate it within Parallels.

**If I activate Windows 7 from within Parallels, will that kill the activation when I boot into Windows 7 using Boot Camp?**

Comment: I had absolutely no issues with [Windows XP on Boot Camp/VMware](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003426), but [this VMware KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1015925) mentions that you might need two keys. [This thread](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/genuinewindows7/thread/21896171-50f3-4808-b1f9-619442896e4e) suggests there are problems using Windows 7 with Boot Camp/Parallels. As I'm not 100% sure on this, I post as comment, as it might help nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Two different machines (Not at the same time):

Parallels 6 + Snow Leopard = No
Parallels 7 + Lion = No